# Please only give hints, not answer: if $g(x)=e^{-x}\sin x-\cos x$ what is $g^{-1}(1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**question**
$g(x)=e^{-x}*\sin x-\cos x$

what is $ g^{-1}(1)$

**my steps**
i know that
$1=e^{-x}\sin x-\cos x$
thus 
$\ln 1=-x\sin x-\cos x$

here is a possibility:
$\ln^21=(-x-2x\sin x\cos x)^2 $
and that is where i got stuck

Comment: "thus $\ln1=-x\sin x-\cos x$" : *No*. Just like most functions, $\ln$ does not have the property of simplifying everything.

Comment: Another dire mistake of algebra is "$(-x\sin x-\cos x)^2=-x^2-2x^2\sin x\cos x$", but let us not get into unnecessary details.

Comment: There are things royally wrong with some of your steps.

Comment: Since some people seemed to wrongly assume that all the roots are in the form $g^{-1}(1)=\{(2k+1)\pi\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}$, I'll point out that, according to wolframalpha, the smallest positive solution of $g(x)=1$ is [a real number $x\approx 3.047$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+e%5E(-x)sin+x-cos+x-1+in+%5B0,10%5D). In fact, [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) and [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+9.4245%3C+x%3C9.4248) show what happens next to the roots $\pi$ and $3\pi$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: What do you mean by "real number"?

Comment: @TonyK Just, well, an element of $\Bbb R$. Quite uninformative, but what I meant was "a generic real number" or "a real number which is likely not to have a special name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $e^{−x}$ is difficult to evaluate for even simple values, so if you can find the root by hand, there must be some way to offset, or negate the effort of calculating $e^{−x}$. $\sin x$ must have a value that makes the value of $e^{−x}$ irrelevant.

Comment: It appears that you cannot "neutralise" $e^{-x}$: in fact, according to wolframalpha, the smallest positive solution of $g(x)=1$ is [a real number $x\approx 3.047$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+e%5E(-x)sin+x-cos+x-1+in+%5B0,10%5D). [This zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) and [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+9.4245%3C+x%3C9.4248) show what happens next to the roots $\pi$ and $3\pi$.

Comment: Correct. I figured this out yesterday. We are likely to get a significant subset of $f^{-1}(1)$ with this method, but not the whole. In fact, such  a root's existence was going to be inevitable once you study the values of the function in a neighbourhood of the point $\pi$. What I meant,of course, (OP DON"T READ THIS) is to put $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(x)=1$ in that case.

Answer (score 2):

$g^{-1}(1)$ is the value $a$ such that $g(a) = 1$. So we're looking for a value that comes out to a nice round number when we plug it into $g$.

The functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ have "nice" values at integer multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $e^x = 1$ if $x=0$, so maybe try some of those possibilities.

Comment: Alsa, it appears that $g^{-1}(1)\ne\{(2k+1)\pi\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}$. According to wolframalpha, the smallest positive solution of $g(x)=1$ is [a real number $x\approx 3.047$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+e%5E(-x)sin+x-cos+x-1+in+%5B0,10%5D). In fact, [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) and [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+9.4245%3C+x%3C9.4248) show what happens next to the roots $\pi$ and $3\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

There's one "obvious" answer: try some small numbers whose sine and cosine you know.  But the function is not one-to-one on $\mathbb R$, and there are infinitely many other real values $x$, not expressible in "closed form", for which $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: I'm curious how you know that there is no closed form expression for the pre images?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**-You just need to guess for real $x$ for which $e^{-x}sinx$ is zero and $cosx=-1$. As $e^{-x}$ is not zero for finite real $x$, your work is reduced to find $x$ for which $sinx=0$ and $cosx=-1$.

Comment: You seem to wrongly assume that all the roots are in the form $g^{-1}(1)=\{(2k+1)\pi\,:\, k\in\Bbb Z\}$, I'll point out that, according to wolframalpha, the smallest positive solution of $g(x)=1$ is [a real number $x\approx 3.047$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+e%5E(-x)sin+x-cos+x-1+in+%5B0,10%5D). In fact, [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) and [this zoomed graphic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+9.4245%3C+x%3C9.4248) show what happens next to the roots $\pi$ and $3\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Show that each interval $[2\pi n,2\pi(n+1)]$ (with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$) contains **exactly two** values of $x$ for which $e^{-x}\sin x-\cos x=1$  by considering the two possibilities $\sin x=0$ and $\sin x\not=0$ separately.  When $\sin x=0$, you should be able to find the value of $x$ precisely.  When $\sin x\not=0$, draw a sketch of the two curves

$$y=e^{-x}\quad\text{and}\quad y={1+\cos x\over\sin x}$$

**Additional hint** (if you get stuck sketching the curve $y=(1+\cos x)/\sin x$):

> $${1+\cos x\over\sin x}=\cot(x/2)$$ and the cotangent decreases monotonically from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

See the graph of the function and you ca easily see the answer:
[image]

Comment: Not so evident to me that [$g(x)=1$ for $x\approx 3.047$ and $x=\pi$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+e%5E(-x)sin+x-cos+x-1+in+%5B3,3.2%5D)

Comment: The graph shows that the only positive values of $x$ for which $g(x) = 1$, $x=(2n+1)\pi$. $3.047$ is close to $\pi$. For $x=3.047$, Excel gives $g(x) = 1.00016$.

Comment: [This zoomed graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) shows otherwise. I guess you'll find out that $g(3.046)<1$ (and now... Bolzano-Weierstrass).

Comment: I know $g < 1$ around $\pi$. Clearly $g(\pi) = 1$. Hence the inaccuracy in EXCEL may be due to rounding off errors.

Comment: Listen, wolframalpha (being Mathematica-based) is way more precise than EXCEL. Rouding [$g(3.046)\approx 0.99972891$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-3.046)sin(3.046)-cos(3.046)) and [$g(3.047)\approx 1.00001602$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-3.047)sin(3.047)-cos(3.047)) to the eight decimal digit is well within its precision. The existence of those roots cannot be dismissed as roundoff error.

Comment: OK, Thanks. The function looks to be more mysterious than it appears at first sight.

Answer (score -2):

See the graph. g (x) is period and hence inverse does not exist. So you are left with numerical analysis..[image]

Comment: Your $a$ and $b$ will be dependent on $e^{-x}$, which does not simplify the problem.

Comment: After the edit: that graphic is actually misleading, since it appears that right next to (and very closed to) each obvious positive solution $x=2k\pi+\pi$ of $g(x)-1=0$, there are non-trivial ones. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+3%3C+x%3C3.2) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)sin+x+-cos+x-1;+9.4245%3C+x%3C9.4248).

Comment: Then how will you solve it?

Comment: I fear the only viable options are numerical methods (I'm not very knowledgeable of non-elementary sections of analytic functions, though)

Comment: Well, "numerical methods" means that you do not "solve it". You just (make a machine) approximate the solutions the best you can, typically with quite undescriptive methods such as Newton-Raphson. In that case, what you may need to do is describe how to find a starting point that guarantees convergence to each desired root.